# Resource consumption RocksBD on Kafka Stream App

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams, rocksdb

I am trying to figure out the resources needed when utilizing RocksDB on Kafka Streams apps and I am a bit confused trying to do some preliminary resource planning for my application.

My issue revolves around local state stores and how they are connected with RocksDB storage engine. I understand that each local state store is backed up by a changelog topic on Kafka Brokers and records are forwarded periodically there. But what happens internally to the Kafka Streams app is what bothers me.

To my understanding RocksDB updates its key-value store every time a new records is forwarded to these local state stores. But how does it handles that ? I mean what is the memory consumption and the overhead created for these stores on behalf of RocksDB. Each local state store is assigned to a Kafka streams task, does RocksDB also allocates some memory per local state store, per task or does it assigns globally for all state stores in the app ?

To be more concrete with an example, consider that I have an application with 10 partitions/tasks and 2 local state stores. Do I need to anticipate significant memory resource allocation on the machine that will host my Kafka app and to what extend can I predict my resource consumption?

Also what is the disk I/O overhead produced by RocksDB on its default configuration on a Kafka stream app ? Does it utilizes the  memtables and again to what extend, or does it flush writes immediately to the local disk ?

Comment: https://docs.confluent.io/current/streams/developer-guide/memory-mgmt.html + https://docs.confluent.io/current/streams/sizing.html

Comment: Thanks for the links, I just need to clarify something for RocksDB "The default block cache size is 50MB per store". The 50MB refers to each local store created (namely one for each partition/task) or is it shared among all tasks ?

Comment: I want to think it's per instance. Meaning if you only have one instance and num.stream.threads to 1 (the default), then there's only one store for all partitions. Haven't really tried it yet, so I'm not sure